# WebBrowser disable/drop persistent cookie

Tags: c#, cookies, browser

Well i'm having a problem with a cookie thats displaying a "Windows Security Warning - Cookie" after executing wb.Dispose().

[image]

**My code**

```
string url = "myweb.com";
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate(url);
while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }
//Fill a form
//Invoke Button
wb.Dispose();
```

**Question:**
I dont want to use that cookie, i just want the fastest way to skip it so this msg wont popup.

**Tried**

1)I tried changing IE settings to "Override automatic cookie handling" and setting first+third party cookies to "Block"

2)

```
webBrowser.Navigate("javascript:void((function(){var a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split('; ');for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b='.'+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:%5C.|[^%5C.]+)/,'')){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,'')){document.cookie=(a[e]+'; domain='+b+'; path='+c+'; expires='+new Date((new Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}})())")`
```

3) Changing Local Policies **Turn off the Security Settings Check feature** to Enabled

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169955/how-can-i-stop-a-webbrowser-control-from-showing-cookie-security-warnings

Comment: checked but it didnt help.

Comment: what version of IE you are running?

Comment: Im using version 9.0.8112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have selected "Override automatic cookie handling" mode in Advanced settings for cookie. You can check that in "Internet Options"->"Privacy"->"Advanced". There is a help on [Managing Cookies in Internet Explorer 9](http://seo.gotwebhost.com/managing-cookies-in-internet-explorer-9/)